# Selecting ALL data from a MySQL Database based on a certain Month from a Date string

Tags: php, mysql

In my database, I have a column called 'created_date' which stores the data the record was created in the following format: 19-Sep-2020.

Is it possible to select all data from the database where the month in the created_date is, for example: Aug, Sep, Oct etc.

`SELECT * FROM data_import WHERE monthname(created_date) = 'Aug';` doesn't seem to work. I get the following error multiple times...

Warning: #1292 Incorrect datetime value: ''

Any help I would appreciate!

Comment: The format of dates stored on a date datatype column is YYYY-mm-dd  yours appears to be stored in a character datatype. You could use instr to test.

Comment: @P.Salmon the date is sent to the database from a PHP script and it's important it remains in that format.

Comment: It's highly unlikely that it's important that the date remain in that format, and, in the highly unlikely event that it were, then you'd simply store the 'format' alongside the date data type.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps INSTR would do

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> select instr('19-Sep-2020','sep');
+----------------------------+
| instr('19-Sep-2020','sep') |
+----------------------------+
|                          4 |
+----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> select instr('19-Sep-2020','aug');
+----------------------------+
| instr('19-Sep-2020','aug') |
+----------------------------+
|                          0 |
+----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)
```

and specially tailored for you :-

```
SELECT * FROM data_import WHERE instr('created_date','Sep') > 0
```

Comment: SELECT * FROM `data_import` WHERE `created_date` = instr('created_date','Sep') am I using that right?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * from data_import where 
DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(created_date,'%d-%b-%Y'),"%b")='Aug';
```

Comment: Corrected the answer